# How to pop a balloon precisely over an image grid that is responsive cross-browser safe?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, safari, responsive-design

I am trying to have a balloon pop up above an image depending what value was passed to the page through PHP code.

The problem is that my solution is a bit messy on Safari, and I amm not sure why I am getting errors there. The slider is showing way too much to the right. I tested Firefox, IE, and Chrome, and all render semi-OK, but Safari does the worst job doing so.

Here’s it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usyf6eew/).

And code, jQuery:

```
$().ready(function () {
    var score = 64;
    var i = 0;
    $('.hers').find('.cll').each(function () {
        if (score != null) {
            if (i == score) {
                var me = $(this);
                me.append(' ' + score);
                bubbleMe(me);
                $(window).resize(function () {
                    bubbleMe(me);
                });
            }
            i++;
        }
    });

    function bubbleMe(me) {
        $('.bubbleImage').css('left', me.position().left - 7);
        $('.bubbleImage').css('top', me.position().top - 7);
        $('.bubbleImage').css('background-image', 'url("http://olthofhomes.com/dev/communities/img/Slider_30_60.png")');
        $('.bubbleImage').css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.cll, .cll:empty {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% / 155);
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 101;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.bubbleImage {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

**HTML (Generated 155 or so DIV's using PHP, and each have 100% / 155th width)**

```
<div class="hers" style="margin-left: 5px;">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="cll"></div>
    <div class="bubbleImage"></div> <a href="#hersindex"><img src="http://olthofhomes.com/dev/images/hers.jpg" class="imgHers" width="100%"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used jQuery Slider instead. Should also be cross-browser safe.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#slider").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 160,
            value: <?php echo $model['HERSScore']; ?>
        });

        $('#slider .ui-slider-handle').text("<?php echo $model['HERSScore']; ?>");
    });
</script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<img src="hers.jpg" id="slider_image">
</div>
```

Some CSS

```
<style>
    .container99 {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        border: 0px solid black;
        position: relative;
    }

    #slider {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 5px);
        height: 0px;
        border: 0;
    }

    #slider_image {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .ui-slider a {
        outline:none;
    }

    #slider .ui-slider-handle {
        background-image: url(communities/img/Slider_30_60.png);
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-color: green;
        border: 0;
        width: 30px;
        padding: 0 0 0 7px;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
```